# How to move to next slide automatically after a fixed time?

Tags: slideshows

I wish to perform a user experiment for which I need to create a slide show so that the transition from one slide to the next should take place automatically after 30 sec (say). I also want to display the time remaining for the current slide.
 Actually, each slide will have a question with some options and the user is supposed to choose one. If the user responds earlier than 30 sec, in that case, it should automatically move to the next slide without waiting for 30 sec.

Comment: And do you want to stop the user from halting or reversing this advance?

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Actually, each slide will have a question with some options and the user is supposed to choose one. If the user responds earlier than 30 sec, it should automatically move to the next slide.

Comment: Do you want me to edit the question I posted?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : I've edited my question.